# Excel Workbook Open event from within an addin?

Tags: events, excel, excel-2007, vba

I am trying to trigger a macro to run when an Excel document is opened.

The problem I am running into is that all of my code resides within an Excel add-in. The Workbook_Open event doesn't work because I can't put the code in individual documents, I need it to reside in the add-in and run whenever any document is opened.

Is there a way to modify the Workbook_Open event or is there another way to trigger a macro when a different document is opened?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use an Application event. There is a good writeup on how to do this at Chip Pearson's site [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx).

Comment: That link doesn't exist any more. Check this instead http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/buildexceladdin05.asp