# Excel Opened Documents History Log - AddIn

Tags: vba, excel

Apologies in advance if this ends up being generic. I have done some research on this and drawn a complete blank.

Excel is great, I love Excel. So much so that the "Recent Documents" section is of almost no use to me as I use that many spreadsheets in an insane amount of locations.

I have been researching a way to log (using VBA as an AddIn) documents when they are opened. Even if it is into something as simple as a text file with the date, however I cannot figure out how to have the VBA code "know" when a file is opened (which, along with outputting to a Text file, is all I want it to do at this stage).

Is there a way to have the VBA look for this action from within an excel instance?

Comment: I think you will find your answer when you look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/8419728/1967396, and in particular the link to http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx which describes how to do this.

Comment: are all of those worksheets macro enabled? If they aren't then how are you planning to run an event

Comment: @mehow it is my understanding that if you have an add-in that runs application events, and it is the one that monitors all "workbook open" events and logs them, then the individual worksheets don't need to be enabled.

Comment: @Floris oh, I have totally misread the Application concept! Youre right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following steps (adapted from the excellent post at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx ) is the "minimally viable" way to do what you need.

1. open a new workbook
2. open the VB editor
3. Insert a class module; in the properties window, set class name to `CExcelEvents`
4. Add the following code in the class module:

```
    Private WithEvents App As Application

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Set App = Application
        MsgBox "initialized the class!"
    End Sub

    Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
        MsgBox "New Workbook was opened: " & Wb.Name
    End Sub
```

5.  Right-click on the "ThisWorkbook" element in the project explorer, and select "View Code"
  6.  Add the following code:

```
Private XLApp As CExcelEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set XLApp = New CExcelEvents
End Sub
```

This creates an instance of the CExcelEvents class, and "turns on event handling" when the addIn is loaded.

Finally, save the file as `myEvents.xlam` in the location where addIns are stored - this varies depending on your machine...

If you now close the file, and add the addIn (again, depends on your environment whether that is from the Developer ribbon or the Tools menu), you should see a dialog box that says "initialized the class!". This shows the addIn is properly installed and working.

Now, when you open a workbook, another message box will appear: "New Workbook was opened: " with the name.

Obviously you will want to get rid of the message boxes, and put in some "useful" code that does whatever you want to do (for example, log the name of the workbook to a file). It sounds to me like you don't need help with the latter - if I am wrong then please let me know.

Comment: That is pretty much exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Did check Chip Pearson's website but must have missed it (that site really is a godsend for VBA!)

Comment: Yes - Chip's website is an excellent resource, but can be "rich". The answer I had linked earlier gets you to the right place, but even then it can be tricky to turn these things exactly into what you want. I figured a "smallest piece of code" might be useful beyond what you need today, so I decided to write it. And I might use it myself some day... Glad it's useful for you.

Comment: +1 for this answer. I think many future readers may find this useful