# Add Worksheet_Change event into an add-in macro who loads an Workbook and creates a new WorkSheet

Tags: excel, events, dynamically-generated, worksheet, vba

I am wondering if it could be possible if I use an add-in to load an workbbook

```
If rdbSpecReportFilePath <> "" Then  
      Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(rdbSpecReportFilePath)
End If
```

and in this workbook I create a certain worksheet (with a specific name).
After putting the data in it, I want, for a specific range, to apply the `Worksheet_Change` event on a specific range, in case the used does some modification by hand, to be able to modify automatically some messages.
Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to build and add-in or edit an add-in? Or just use Excel VBA programming and make it?

Comment: I have the add-in. I want to add a new functionality that loads an Excel file, read the data from that Excel, create a new sheet in the loaded Excel and in that sheet the user needs to edit a cell. I want to have that event there

Comment: Refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8419824/7690982), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261058/can-i-trigger-the-workbook-sheetchange-event-from-a-different-workbook) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832271/catch-an-event-in-a-different-workbook).

Comment: This is a solution. Thanks!